# Spark/YARN - not all nodes are used in spark-submit

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, namenode

I have a Spark/YARN cluster with 3 slaves setup on AWS.

I spark-submit a job like this: `~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster my.py` And the final result is a file containing all the hostnames from all the slaves in a cluster. I was expecting I get a mix of hostnames in the output file, however, I only see one hostname in the output file. That means YARN never utilize the other slaves in the cluster.

**Am I missing something in the configuration?**

I have also included my `spark-env.sh` settings below.

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
YARN_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/

SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=3
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=3
```

my.py

```
import socket
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def get_ip_wrap(num):
    return socket.gethostname()

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('appName')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = [x for x in range(1, 100)]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)

result = distData.map(get_ip_wrap)
result.saveAsTextFile('hby%s'% str(time.time()))
```

Answer (score 0):

After I updated the following setting or spark-env.sh, all slaves are utilized.

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=3
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=8
```

Comment: You may be overcommitting your memory. If a task doesn't require all the machines, then it'll scale down accordingly